# How to calculate mean number of something per client in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, mean, teradata-sql-assistant

I have table in Teradata SQL like below:

```
SMS_ID | CLIENT_ID 
-------------------
11     | 123   
22     | 123
33     | 123
87     | 456
89     | 456
14     | 888
```

- Column "SMS_ID" presents ID of SMS sent do client
- Column "CLINET_ID" presents ID of client which received SMS

My question is: How can I calculate in Teradata SQL mean number of SMS per CLIENT ?

If I calculate correctly, mean number of SMS per client im my example is 2 because (3+2+1) / 3 = 2

Comment: https://www.teradatapoint.com/teradata/teradata-avg-average-function.htm

Comment: Nathatn_Sqv, could you present your proposition on my data ?

Comment: Do you want mean number of SMS for senders or receivers?

Comment: receivers in general (so probably 2 in my example because (3+2+1) / 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First aggregate and find the counts for each client, then subquery the and take the average of the entire table.

```sql
SELECT AVG(cnt)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's query can be simplified to *number of rows divided by number of clients*:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENT_ID)
FROM yourTable
```

Which one is more efficient depends on your actual data.

Comment: Connect via LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/mwlite/in/tim-biegeleisen-557aa38