# How to calculate mean value per group in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, average, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

have table in Teradata SQL like below:

```
SMS_ID | PRODUCT 
-------------------
11     | A
22     | A
33     | A
87     | B
89     | B
14     | C
```

- Column "SMS_ID" presents ID of SMS sent do client
- Column "PRODUCT" presents ID of product which was a subject of SMS

My question is: How can I calculate in Teradata SQL mean number of SMS per PRODUCT ?
As a result I need something like below:

```
AVG  | PRODUCT
-------
0.5  | A   -> because 3 / 6 = 0.5
0.33 | B   -> because 2 / 6 = 033
0.16 | C   -> because 1 / 6 = 0.16
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate mean number of something per client in Teradata SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739424/how-to-calculate-mean-number-of-something-per-client-in-teradata-sql)

Comment: Yes, but it question does not answer on my current, new problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want fractions of the total count:

```
SELECT
    product
   ,COUNT(*)  -- count per product
      / CAST(SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS FLOAT) -- total count = sum of counts per procuct
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY PRODUCT
```